# Authenticate to Azure DevOps from a Function App Powershell script

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure-devops, azure-functions, rest

How do I authenticate to Azure DevOps to create a work item, using a Powershell script from a Function App? I am invoking DevOps APIs and it is working with Personal Access Token. But I want to avoid PAT, since it is tied to a user account. My current script is as shown below.

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = 'njr2jXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
$Header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/myTeam/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0"
$sprints = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use OAuth 2.0 which id described here in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)